# Is it possible to get viewer retention data from third party YouTube channels?

Tags: youtube, youtube-analytics-api

So, with the help of the YouTube Analytics API it's possible to get viewer retention of your own channel.

But is it maybe possible (maybe with the YouTube Data API v3) to get the viewer retention of every channel out there?

I tried to get the viewer retention data somehow through the "default" YouTube Data API v3. Unfortunately there is no API call for that.

Comment: By *every channel out there* you mean any channel that you haven't any particular access to? If so, it seems clear that *unfortunately* YouTube won't give you this information.

Comment: You may have to provide some code snippet for what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for is private user data in order to see it you need the consent of the owner of the channel that's why YouTube analytics will only give you your data.

The YouTube data API will also only give you channel information for the currently authenticated user.

You can't see the information you are looking for unless you have access to the channel.

Comment: That makes sense. But is there any chance to get at least the retention data of a single video? Because there are also parts of it in the videos‘ timelines.

Comment: Not unless you own or have access to the video in question.